# Shortest way of creating an object in C#

Tags: c#

For some reason, I don't like initializing an object and then assign values to it in two lines, I want it to be done in just 1 line, This is what I am doing now,

```
ObjectA oA = new ObjectA();
            oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow);
```

can I make it short to something like,

```
new ObjectA() oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow);
```

Comment: `ObjectA oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow);`

Comment: It's unclear why you're *ever* doing the first form. It's ignoring the initial value of `oA`...

Comment: why so many negative votes :-(, some people just don't know these shortcuts

Comment: Your code isn't assigning all of the values of the object you create with values based on another object.  It's creating an object, then throwing that object away, creating a *new* object, and populating that with the values based on the other object.  Not only is it more code in the file, but it's pointless code that is wasting effort at runtime too.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes. The question itself might seem silly to those familiar with C#, but it still a correctly written and correctly formatted question. Downvotes are for badly written questions, not because the answer is trivial.

Comment: @AndySavage: Voting doesn't only concern decent formatting of your question. The downvote buttons says it can be applied to questions without research and useless questions. (I am not arguing whether downvoting this question is okay or not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of those situations where trying something that looks like it makes logical sense works perfectly.

`ObjectA oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow);`

Or if you prefer, you can let the compiler figure out the type:

`var oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow);`

When you do

```
ObjectA oA = new ObjectA();
oA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(someDBRow)
```

What's happening is as follows:

In the first line, you create a variable named `oA`, and put an instance of `ObjectA` into it.

Then, in the second line, you throw away that instance that you created with the `new` keyword, and put a brand new instance in the variable. It's wasteful.

Comment: Your answer is identical to mine, and 100% correct. +1 for you, sir. (Removed my answer)